# Downloading Excel in React from NET Core API: Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': Overload resolution failed

Tags: reactjs, .net-core, download, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a WebAPI in .NET Core that creates an excel file and returns it to the function on the front-end, built in React.

Signaure of the methods in the API:

```
[HttpGet("export")]
public IActionResult Export([FromQuery] SalespriceParams param, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

It's a large method but at the end it creates and returns the excel file, the package used is EPPlus:

```
var stream = new MemoryStream();  

using (var package = new ExcelPackage(stream))
{
    var workSheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("export");
    workSheet.Cells.LoadFromCollection(result, true);
    package.Save();
}
stream.Position = 0;                  

return File(stream, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", "export.xlsx");
```

But saving the file in React fails. I have tried with POST and GET methods but either the downloads give an error, or the parameters are not passed to the backend, and the data isn't filtered and returned as all rows.

This the latest version of my method in the front-end:

```js
const Excel = {
    export: (params: URLSearchParams) => {
        axios.get(`/excel/export`, {params: {params}, headers: {'responseType: blob'}}).then((responseBody) => {      
            const link = document.createElement('a');
            const url = URL.createObjectURL(responseBody.data);
            console.log(url);
            link.href = url;
            const date = new Date();
            link.download = 'export.xlsx';
            link.click();       
        })
    }
}
```

Latest error message: `Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': Overload resolution failed. Moreover SalespriceParams param do is empty and contains only default values.`

The response is not recognized as blob I think in the case.

I switched from GET to POST request in both the back and front-end.
I also tried creating a blob from the result with new `Blob(...)` before downloading.

The goal is that the Excel file is downloaded to the local computer.

If I omit `responseType: 'blob'`, the parameters are passed to the backend

```
export: (params: URLSearchParams) => {
    axios.get(`/excel/export`, {params}).then((responseBody) => {      
        const link = document.createElement('a');
        const url = URL.createObjectURL(responseBody.data);
        console.log(url);
        link.href = url;
        const date = new Date();
        link.download = 'export.xlsx';
        ink.click();       
    })
}
```

But the download fails again with the same error (`Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL'`) as it now has no indication that it will be a blob.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting `headers: {responseType: blob'}` which is seems to be not correct. to make it work you should provide as part of Axios' `responseType` option, not under `headers`.

Below is the sample code you can try:

```
const Excel = {
  export: (params) => {
    axios.get(`/excel/export`, {
      params: params,
      responseType: 'blob' 
    }).then((response) => {
      const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
      const link = document.createElement('a');
      link.href = url;
      link.setAttribute('download', 'export.xlsx'); 
      document.body.appendChild(link);
      link.click();
      window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url); 
    }).catch(error => {
      console.error('Download error:', error);
    });
  }
};
```

Make sure that the API method is using the correct parameter binding. You configured the URLSearchParams in a way that might not be compatible with `[FromQuery]`. Make sure your query parameters are named consistently on both ends, like this:

```
const params = new URLSearchParams({
  startDate: '2021-01-01',
  endDate: '2021-12-31'
});
Excel.export(params);
```

This will result in a URL constructed with the query string like:

```
`/excel/export?startDate=2021-01-01&endDate=2021-12-31`
```

On the server side, ensure `SalespriceParams` can bind from the query string with public setters for its properties:

```
public class SalespriceParams
{
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    // Other properties...
}
```

Make sure your .NET Core API can bind `SalespriceParams` from the query string.

Comment: Thans you so much. It was in passing in the parameters correctly:  {params: params, responseType: 'blob' }